# Computing approximated intersection volume between two heightmaps

Tags: graphics, 3d, gis

The heightmap is a structured grid of points (see picture).

We can easily compute the length of the vertical segments that represent the difference between the two heightmaps.

The question is: how could I compute the approximate intersection volume between the two?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have 2 height maps h1(x,y) and h2(x,y).
To calculate volume between:

1. Calculate relative height map h = h2-h1.
2. Set h=0 if h<0, or make h=abs(h), depends on purpose.
3. Integrate h(x,y) by dxdy over the region of interest.

Comment: Should I put two triangles on top of the 4 cell's vertical segments and compute the volume underlying them?

Comment: Forget about triangles. You have a 2d function of x and y. The volume under the surface is a result of function integration by dimensions.